# Depth of an inhabitable shell around the earth?

Tags: science-based, space-travel, earth-like, space-constructs

Premise: Synthetic life forms have (built, grown, or by any other feasible means) created a layer around the Earth.  Assume these life forms require no comforts for the work, only energy which is at a quasi-infinite supply.  Ideally, once complete, I would want the climate and atmospheric strata to remain as close to the current real-world Earth as possible for story telling purposes.

***Realistically, how thick would this have to be to be habitable, farmable and stable enough to hold up cities, and what could be some of the technologies used to hold the shell up?***

I'm happy to migrate the question if you guys think it would do better on another site.  Please advise...

Comment: This looks to be several questions in one.  I would recommend breaking it down into more easily answered questions.  You can even ask one or two and base the future questions on your answers to the earlier ones.

Comment: your shell does not need to hold itself up. It just has to be stable enough not to implode. Conveniently enough, a sphere is exactly the right shape for that purpose.

Comment: Expanding on what bowlturner said, asking "What questions am I not asking?" is a red flag for a question being "too broad." I would suggest you not ask that question. Also, welcome to the site.